# PA_WCMLocalRendering missing

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

Installed portal 7 with WCM, WCMLocalRendering is missing ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the ConfigEngine task

```
./ConfigEngine.sh configure-wcm-authoring -DPortalAdminPwd=password -DWasPassword=password
```

It is also possible that it is called PA_WCMLRingJSR286 or something similar though.

Answer (score -1):

I would submit your issues to IBM Software Support.  They don't charge per instance, it's unlimited amount of requests as long as you have a support agreement.

Comment: I don't believe I should be voted down.  The reason is that this is a software installation issue and the only way to fix is to call the vendor.   People can suggest monkeying with the software but how would you really know if you fixed it the correct way.

Comment: He either installed administrative installation (which doesn't come with the WCM applications) or installed from wrong media set (there are media sets without the WCM applications). We're looking at a beginner error, and most likely Jack should have bothered to read the basic installation instructions... There is no need to bother IBM with such.